# filter pyspark df by max date and date range

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a df which has a date column, and some more columns i want to first get the latest date(max(date)) from the date column. and from that max date, i want to filter the df to only those rows which has the date from **last seven days before the max date** (including max date).

For example, if the max date is 2021-01-20. then, then filter should keep dates from

```
2021-01-20(including max date)

2021-01-19

2021-01-18

2021-01-17

2021-01-16

2021-01-15

2021-01-14
```

and filter out rest of the dates.
I want to filter the enire df based on the this date range.
I am using spark 3.0 (pyspark)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a column of the max date, and do a filter to get the rows which are within 7 days of the max date.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'maxdate', 
    F.max('date').over(Window.orderBy(F.lit(1)))
).filter('date >= maxdate - interval 7 days').drop('maxdate')
```

Comment: Can you please explain
`  F.max('date').over(Window.orderBy(F.lit(1)))` 
what exactly this line is doing in the code. want to understand the concept here.

Comment: @ritzen101 that gets the max date over all rows. A dummy window (ordered by a dummy column) is needed to aggregate over all rows.